# Plotting within a for loop, with 'hold on' effect in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

Using Matplotlib, I want to get one plot that connects multiple points. The plot commands are within a for loop. Right now, I am getting one figure each, and having to close the first one to open the second.

The desired effect is shown in this Matlab graph:
[image]

Each point is at an even-numbered N.

How do I do this by modifying my current Python code? The important pieces are the last 4 lines, and the very first for loop on Line 7.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

y = 5
x = 2
for N in range(x,x+y,2):
    #Constants and parameters
    epsilon = 0.01
    K00 = np.logspace(0,3,10,10)
    len1 = len(K00)
    y0 = [0]*(3*N/2+3)
    Kplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
    Pplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
    S = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2+1)]
    KS = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    PS = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    Splot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2+1)]
    KSplot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    PSplot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]

    for series in range(0,len1):
        K0 = K00[series]
        Q = 10
        r1 = 0.0001
        r2 = 0.001
        a = 0.001
        d = 0.001
        k = 0.999
        S10 = 1e5
        P0 = 1
        tf = 1e10
        time = np.linspace(0,tf,len1)

        #Defining dy/dt's
        def f(y,t):
            for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
                S[alpha] = y[alpha]
            for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
                KS[beta-N/2-1] = y[beta]
            for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
                PS[gamma-N-1] = y[gamma]
            K = y[3*N/2+1]
            P = y[3*N/2+2]

            # The model equations
            ydot = np.zeros((3*N/2+3,1))
            B = range((N/2)+1,N+1)
            G = range(N+1,3*N/2+1)
            runsumPS = 0
            runsum1 = 0
            runsumKS = 0
            runsum2 = 0

            for m in range(0,N/2):
                runsumPS = runsumPS + PS[m]
                runsum1 = runsum1 + S[m+1]
                runsumKS = runsumKS + KS[m]
                runsum2 = runsum2 + S[m]
                ydot[B[m]] = a*K*S[m]-(d+k+r1)*KS[m]

            for i in range(0,N/2-1):
                ydot[G[i]] = a*P*S[i+1]-(d+k+r1)*PS[i]

            for p in range(1,N/2):
                ydot[p] = -S[p]*(r1+a*K+a*P)+k*KS[p-1]+d*(PS[p-1]+KS[p])

            ydot[0] = Q-(r1+a*K)*S[0]+d*KS[0]+k*runsumPS
            ydot[N/2] = k*KS[N/2-1]-(r2+a*P)*S[N/2]+d*PS[N/2-1]
            ydot[G[N/2-1]] = a*P*S[N/2]-(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2-1]
            ydot[3*N/2+1] = (d+k+r1)*runsumKS-a*K*runsum2
            ydot[3*N/2+2] = (d+k+r1)*(runsumPS-PS[N/2-1])- \
                            a*P*runsum1+(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2-1]

            ydot_new = []
            for j in range(0,3*N/2+3):
                ydot_new.extend(ydot[j])
            return ydot_new

        # Initial conditions
        y0[0] = S10
        for i in range(1,3*N/2+1):
            y0[i] = 0
        y0[3*N/2+1] = K0
        y0[3*N/2+2] = P0

        # Solve the DEs
        soln = odeint(f,y0,time, mxstep = 5000)
        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            S[alpha] = soln[:,alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            KS[beta-N/2-1] = soln[:,beta]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            PS[gamma-N-1] = soln[:,gamma]

        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            Splot[alpha][series] = soln[len1-1,alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            KSplot[beta-N/2-1][series] = soln[len1-1,beta]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            PSplot[gamma-N-1][series] = soln[len1-1,gamma]

        u1 = 0
        u2 = 0
        u3 = 0

        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            u1 = u1 + Splot[alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            u2 = u2 + KSplot[beta-N/2-1]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            u3 = u3 + PSplot[gamma-N-1]

        K = soln[:,3*N/2+1]
        P = soln[:,3*N/2+2]
        Kplot[series] = soln[len1-1,3*N/2+1]
        Pplot[series] = soln[len1-1,3*N/2+2]
        utot = u1+u2+u3

    #Plot
    Kcrit = abs((Q/r2)*(1+epsilon)-utot)
    v,i = Kcrit.min(0),Kcrit.argmin(0)
    plt.plot(N,K00[i])
    plt.show()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am correct you only want one plot with all the points you were calculating. If that is the case the easy way is to store all the point and plot them all at the end. So what I will do will be. The need to create two list to store the data x_data_plot and y_data_plot. So the changes will be:

Create the list for store

```
# The data of the plot will be added in these lists
x_data_plot=[]
y_data_plot=[]
```

Store the data in each iteration of the loop

```
# Save the new points for x and y
x_data_plot.append(N)
y_data_plot.append(K00[i])
```

And finally making the plot

```
# Make the plot of all the points together
plt.plot(x_data_plot,y_data_plot)
plt.show()
```

Putting all together

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

y = 5
x = 2
# The data of the plot will be added in these lists
x_data_plot=[]
y_data_plot=[]
for N in range(x,x+y,2):
    #Constants and parameters
    epsilon = 0.01
    K00 = np.logspace(0,3,10,10)
    len1 = len(K00)
    y0 = [0]*(3*N/2+3)
    Kplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
    Pplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
    S = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2+1)]
    KS = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    PS = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    Splot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2+1)]
    KSplot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]
    PSplot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for kkkk in range(N/2)]

    for series in range(0,len1):
        K0 = K00[series]
        Q = 10
        r1 = 0.0001
        r2 = 0.001
        a = 0.001
        d = 0.001
        k = 0.999
        S10 = 1e5
        P0 = 1
        tf = 1e10
        time = np.linspace(0,tf,len1)

        #Defining dy/dt's
        def f(y,t):
            for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
                S[alpha] = y[alpha]
            for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
                KS[beta-N/2-1] = y[beta]
            for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
                PS[gamma-N-1] = y[gamma]
            K = y[3*N/2+1]
            P = y[3*N/2+2]

            # The model equations
            ydot = np.zeros((3*N/2+3,1))
            B = range((N/2)+1,N+1)
            G = range(N+1,3*N/2+1)
            runsumPS = 0
            runsum1 = 0
            runsumKS = 0
            runsum2 = 0

            for m in range(0,N/2):
                runsumPS = runsumPS + PS[m]
                runsum1 = runsum1 + S[m+1]
                runsumKS = runsumKS + KS[m]
                runsum2 = runsum2 + S[m]
                ydot[B[m]] = a*K*S[m]-(d+k+r1)*KS[m]

            for i in range(0,N/2-1):
                ydot[G[i]] = a*P*S[i+1]-(d+k+r1)*PS[i]

            for p in range(1,N/2):
                ydot[p] = -S[p]*(r1+a*K+a*P)+k*KS[p-1]+d*(PS[p-1]+KS[p])

            ydot[0] = Q-(r1+a*K)*S[0]+d*KS[0]+k*runsumPS
            ydot[N/2] = k*KS[N/2-1]-(r2+a*P)*S[N/2]+d*PS[N/2-1]
            ydot[G[N/2-1]] = a*P*S[N/2]-(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2-1]
            ydot[3*N/2+1] = (d+k+r1)*runsumKS-a*K*runsum2
            ydot[3*N/2+2] = (d+k+r1)*(runsumPS-PS[N/2-1])- \
                            a*P*runsum1+(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2-1]

            ydot_new = []
            for j in range(0,3*N/2+3):
                ydot_new.extend(ydot[j])
            return ydot_new

        # Initial conditions
        y0[0] = S10
        for i in range(1,3*N/2+1):
            y0[i] = 0
        y0[3*N/2+1] = K0
        y0[3*N/2+2] = P0

        # Solve the DEs
        soln = odeint(f,y0,time, mxstep = 5000)
        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            S[alpha] = soln[:,alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            KS[beta-N/2-1] = soln[:,beta]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            PS[gamma-N-1] = soln[:,gamma]

        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            Splot[alpha][series] = soln[len1-1,alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            KSplot[beta-N/2-1][series] = soln[len1-1,beta]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            PSplot[gamma-N-1][series] = soln[len1-1,gamma]

        u1 = 0
        u2 = 0
        u3 = 0

        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            u1 = u1 + Splot[alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            u2 = u2 + KSplot[beta-N/2-1]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            u3 = u3 + PSplot[gamma-N-1]

        K = soln[:,3*N/2+1]
        P = soln[:,3*N/2+2]
        Kplot[series] = soln[len1-1,3*N/2+1]
        Pplot[series] = soln[len1-1,3*N/2+2]
        utot = u1+u2+u3

    #Plot
    Kcrit = abs((Q/r2)*(1+epsilon)-utot)
    v,i = Kcrit.min(0),Kcrit.argmin(0)
    # Save the new points for x and y
    x_data_plot.append(N)
    y_data_plot.append(K00[i])

# Make the plot of all the points together
plt.plot(x_data_plot,y_data_plot)
plt.show()
```

This will result in:
[image: Example of result]

If you want a dinamic image is a liitle more complicated but it is possible. Just ask for it.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic image?

Comment: @abscissa I mean some kind of animation. So you will start with an empty image and when a new value is calculated is added to the plot. When you execute the script you will se an empty plot and the points will appear one by one. At the end you will have the exact same plot you get with the script in the answer.